# Checking FieldFile on django form

Tags: django, forms

beginner question. here's pdb output

```
(Pdb) entry.image
<FieldFile: None>
(Pdb) entry.image is None
False
```

how do I check if the image exists or not?

Lets say I want to access entry.image.file but I dont know whether entry.image exists

**SOLVED** check my own answer

Comment: What is a `FieldFile`? Presumably it's a custom model of yours - what does its code look like?

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile entry is a ModelForm, image is a FileField from that model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it

```
bool(entry.image)
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer so that those who come after you will know what to do :)

Comment: I did but she said "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" :). dont know why, I didnt have to wait to do that before

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
file_path = entry.image.path
open(file_path)
```

If the file exists, there should not be any error.

Comment: yes, but I asked how to check the existence of the file. It will give a ValueError ('has no file associated with it') if you try accessing the path or file attribute from entry.image

Comment: ksut, Well, you can always wrap the access statement in a try except.

Comment: yea true. I didnt think it that way back then

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import os
os.path.exists(file_path) and os.path.isfile(file_path)
```

Comment: check prev answer. accessing 'file' or 'path' attribute from the entry.image wont work

Comment: @Kusut: My mistake. Let me dig around a bit.